# SQL 3 Tables Union, Join, In

Tags: sql, join, union

I have a query of a table that brings back a bunch of categories that are active. The goal is to bring back those categories, and in addition: if a Task Order has a category assigned to it that is no longer active, bring it back as well. So say for example there are 10 categories active and 3 inactive and the Task Order is associated one that is inactive, the query would bring back the 10 active plus the 1 inactive category because it's associated with the Task Order.

```
FundingLineCategory Table: FundingLineCategoryID, FundingLineCategoryName, isActive

FundingLine Table: FundingLineID, FundingLineCategoryID, FundingLineName, isActive

Tasker Table: TaskerID, TaskerTypeID, TaskOrderNumber, FundingLineID
```

Initial query

```
SELECT DISTINCT FundingLineCategoryID, FundingLineCategoryName, isActive
FROM FundingLineCategory
WHERE isActive = 1
```

Looks straight forward in the beginning, but the Tasker table only has FundingLineID, we have to get the FundingLineCategoryID which is in the FundingLine table. So I have 2 tables thus far, but not sure how to add the 3rd table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FundingLineCategoryID, FundingLineCategoryName, isActive
FROM FundingLineCategory
WHERE isActive = 1
   OR FundingLineCategoryID IN 
            (SELECT FundingLineID
             FROM Tasker 
             WHERE TaskOrderNumber = 'ABC123' )
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Can you form a query that returns FundingILneCategoryId values for tasks?

Comment: FundingLineCategory Table: FundingLineCategoryID (int), FundingLineCategoryName (varchar 300), isActive (bit)

FundingLine Table: FundingLineID (int), FundingLineCategoryID (int), FundingLineName( varchar 300), isActive (bit)

Tasker Table: TaskerID (int), TaskerTypeID (int), TaskOrderNumber (varchar 100), FundingLineID (int)

Comment: FundingLineCategory Table has about 10 records. Assume all basic. The ID's run from 1 thru 10, assume the names are giraffe, iguana, cat, dog, etc. The FundingLine Table has about 50 records. Assume all basic. The ID's run from 1 thru 50. The FundingLineName is just a name. The FundingLineCategoryID is the same ID from the FundingLineCategory table. The Tasker table has about 2,000 records. The ID's run from 1 thru 2000. The TaskOrderNumber is an alpha/numeric varchar. The FundingLineID is the same as from the FundingLine table.

Comment: Gordon, the desired result is listed above the code in the opening paragraph.